# Objective-C comment documentation on /** @discussion @param @see @return .... */

Tags: objective-c

I've seen more and more of this kind of @marker with comments in /** */ and I'm looking for some documentation, explanation on what they are and how to use it. Thanks!

```
/**
 @param blabla...
 @return bla...
 @see ...
 @method ...
 @discussion ...
 */
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is inline (well, in-comment) documentation, a special approach to self-documenting code. This particular style is called the [Javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) style, and apart from the Javadoc tool, a lot of popular documentation generators support it, including [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#docstructure) and [Appledoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/).

The goal of writing the documentation of some code (an application, a library, etc.) is that developers don't need to maintain the codebase **and** a separate file structure for the documentation; these automatic utilities can generate nicely-formatted (for example, HTML) documentation from the information embedded in the comments.

Also note that this isn't strictly a language-dependent feature. Don't be confused by the @ (at) symbols, this is not Objective-C specific syntax (rather, it is specific to the particular documentation generator program used).

Comment: appledoc (http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/) is a commonly used documentation generator for Objective-C code.

Comment: so i believe the @ syntax is used with appledoc? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: @NicolasManzini Yes, and thus it has nothing to do with the fact it's embedded within (Objective-)C comments.